# Rake script broke in 10.0.1 that use include Rake::DSL

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a number of rake files that include a common module:

```
require 'rake'

module RakeCommon
  include Rake::DSL
  task :clean do
```

And in a rake file:

```
include RakeCommon
```

The problems is that after updating to rake 10.0.1, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `task' for RakeCommon:Module
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `extend` instead of `include`? It seems that Rake::DSL has these methods available as instance methods, not class ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like I stated in comment, but just checked it.

You should use `extend` instead of `include` in your module. Your code was working earlier, because `Rake::DSL` module was extending `Object`. Methods you were using were available in module no matter if you included or extended it properly. In 10.0 branch some deprecated things were removed, that's why it did not work.